# cannot filter in data table?

Tags: c#, winforms

I got an application which display all files in a given directory. And now I want to implement a search function within the application. I use the textBox_textChanged method to implement the search as it is faster. But somehow I cannot get it to work. I don't know what's the problem. Here is my code :

```
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {   private Timer timer;
        private int count;
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataRow dr;
        String[] s1;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {   
            count = 0;
            timer = new Timer();
            timer.Interval = 1000;
            timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
            timer.Start();
            s1 = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\FILE","*.*",SearchOption.AllDirectories);
            for (int i = 0; i <= s1.Length - 1; i++)
            {
                if (i == 0)
                {
                    dt.Columns.Add("File_Name");
                    dt.Columns.Add("File_Type");
                    dt.Columns.Add("File_Size");
                    dt.Columns.Add("Create_Date");
                }

                //Get each file information
                FileInfo info = new FileInfo(s1[i]);
                FileSystemInfo sysInfo = new FileInfo(s1[i]);
                dr = dt.NewRow();
                //Get File name of each file name
                dr["File_Name"] = sysInfo.Name;
                //Get File Type/Extension of each file 
                dr["File_Type"] = sysInfo.Extension;
                //Get File Size of each file in KB format
                dr["File_Size"] = (info.Length / 1024).ToString();
                //Get file Create Date and Time 
                dr["Create_Date"] = sysInfo.CreationTime.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
                //Insert collected file details in Datatable
                dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                //


                if ((info.Length / 1024) > 5000)
                {
                   MessageBox.Show("" + sysInfo.Name + " had reach its size limit.");
                }
            }
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                //Finally Add DataTable into DataGridView
                dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
            } 
        }
        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                count++;
                if (count == 300)
                {
                    count = 0;
                    timer.Stop();
                    Application.Restart();
                }
        }
        public string secondsToTime(int seconds)
        {
             int minutes = 0;
             int hours = 0;

             while (seconds >= 60)
             {
                minutes += 1;
                seconds -= 60;
             }
             while (minutes >= 60)
             {
                hours += 1;
                minutes -= 60;
             }

             string strHours = hours.ToString();
             string strMinutes = minutes.ToString();
             string strSeconds = seconds.ToString();

             if (strHours.Length < 2)
                 strHours = "0" + strHours;
             if (strMinutes.Length < 2)
                 strMinutes = "0" + strMinutes;
             if (strSeconds.Length < 2)
                 strSeconds = "0" + strSeconds;
             return strHours + ":" + strMinutes + ":" + strSeconds;
         }


        //this is the filter code fragment.
        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataRow[] select = dt.Select("File_Name = '" + textBox1.Text+"'");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly "doesn't work".  I don't think too many people want to spend time sifting through your code if you're not specific about the problem.

Comment: sorry about that. I meant exactly what I said that the filter doesn't work. It won't filter even when I enter value into the text box.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using TextChanged, I assume you want to match on partial searches where what you type will match any filenames that your input is contained in. For example, if you type "He" it will match "Help", "HelloWorld", etc.

**Edit:**

Instead of binding directly to your datatable, you should use a [BindingSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms158145.aspx) because it will provide you a filter feature.

```
public BindingSource bindingSource;
```

Then, change this code:

```
if (dt.Rows.Count > 0) 
{ 
    //Finally Add DataTable into DataGridView 
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt; 
}
```

To this:

```
if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    //Finally Add DataTable into DataGridView 
    bindingSource = new BindingSource();
    bindingSource.DataSource = dt;
    dataGridView1.DataSource = bindingSource;
}
```

And finally change your TextChanged event handler to this to do the actual filtering:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bindingSource.Filter = string.Format("File_Name LIKE '%{0}%'", textBox1.Text);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @BradRem. I've tried it but it still doesn't work. My gridview still display all of the files, even when I enter value into the text box.

Comment: @shahrul1509, I don't see where you are actually filtering your gridView.  The Select is probably working, but it's not hooked up to your grid!

Comment: @shahrul1509, updated the code to show how to filter your datagridview as per your request.